# Can jQuery be used as a live html parser/ node replacement utility?

Tags: jquery

Each of my posts have a different keyword they are optimized for. I need a routine that will take the post content and wrap the first instance of my keyword in strong tags. I don't want to decorate the keyword if its (1) part of an element's attribute collection (title, src, alt, etc). And I don't want to decorate it if its in a h1-6 heading tag.

I know there are lots of tools for dom traversal and Html parsing/replacement. Can jQuery do this?

Can someone give any examples of using jQuery as html parser?

Comment: Define "parser". What do you need it to do?

Comment: jQuery is very strong on traversing the DOM, I am not sure what exactly do you mean by parsing/replacement, if you give more details we might be able to give better answer

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ & http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ should give you an impression.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap instances of a predefined keyword in strong tags when its not contained in a heading element or part of an element attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for. You shouldnt be parsing the HTML directly. it's better to traverse the DOM and look for text nodes.

```
var word = "foo";

var nodes = $("postSelector").find("*"); // get all elements

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    // get the node
    var node = nodes.eq(i);
    // if the tagName is a h1-h6 then continue
    if (/h\d/.test(node[0].tagName)) continue;
    if (node.text().indexOf(word) > -1) {
         // handle the textual replacement.
         var text = node.text();
         text.replace(word, "<strong>" + word + "</strong>");
         node.html(text);
    }
}
```

This will cause problems if you have nested html with your words like

`<p> fo <span> o </span> </p>`

That's a completely different issue to solve though.

Comment: @ScottB your reference to posts was a bit vague so you need to have some kind of selector to get a post. I don't know what a post is in your HTML code.

Comment: I see, by $post I'm referring to the wordpress post_content object

Comment: @ScottB Good luck with that, I have no clue what `post_content` is in wordpress